# Let's reopen question about why/how to use workspaces

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, closed-questions, answered-questions

I think we should reopen this question about why and how to use workspaces:

- [What can I use workspaces for, and how can they be used?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192019/how-are-workspaces-useful)

It has some good answers already, but if it's reopened, perhaps even more thorough answers will be posted.

I don't think it's too open-ended...though I could see a possible argument for making it community wiki.

Just one more reopen vote is needed...

Comment: I vtc by mistake,.Yesterday I voted for reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit chatty, a little bit faffy. That's probably the reason is was closed originally.

It would probably be better if it were something along the lines of **What are virtual desktops and why do I want them?** but I'll leave those sorts of dalliances to smarter people.

I've reopened it.